# Determine the isomorphism classes of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Determine the isomorphism classes of the automorphism group of the  group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5$.

We know that $\gcd(2,3,5)=1$. So $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

After that how can I proceed?

Comment: I write gcd(2,3,5)=1

Comment: @user26857 sorry. The actual thing is gcd(2,3)=gcd(2,5)=gcd(3,5)=1.

Comment: I suggest you to include the last comment into the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$

Answer (score 0):

Well as you observed, since $2,3,$ and $5$ are pair-wise co-prime, $$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3 \times \mathbb{Z}/5)\simeq \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2)\times \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3) \times \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/5).$$ Can you continue from here?

Comment: I can't see where exactly the OP observed that $2$, $3$, and $5$ are **pair-wise** coprime.