# Computing $|\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{(Z}/{1155\mathbb Z)}^\times)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Compute $|\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{(Z}/{1155\mathbb Z)}^\times)|$.

I feel puzzled about this problem. I found that
$$\mathbb{(Z}/{1155\mathbb Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{(Z}/3\mathbb Z)^\times \times \mathbb{(Z}/5\mathbb Z)^\times \times \mathbb{(Z}/7\mathbb Z)^\times \times \mathbb{(Z}/{11\mathbb Z)}^\times.
$$
I get the order of itself $\left|\mathbb{(Z}/{1155\mathbb Z)}^\times\right|$, but I don't know how to find its automorphism.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Sorry，I will learn the latex and pay more attention next time.

Comment: The next thing you should do is probably to write that group in a form where the invariant factors show. Like
$$\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_6\times\Bbb{Z}_{10}\simeq\Bbb{Z}_{60}\times\Bbb{Z}_2^3.$$ Do you see how to get there?

Comment: Does $\Bbb{Z}^\times_{1155}$ mean the collection of non-zero elements?

Comment: “https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n”is this mean .but I don not how to type the form correctly on this site via using the code.@Frank Lu,@Jyrki Lahtonen I don‘t know your meaning would you like to teach me more detail about it?

Comment: Jackunir: I wrote the group $\Bbb{Z}_{1155}^*$ as a product of cyclic groups in such a way that the order of a factor always divides those of the preceding ones, or in terms of [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor). I think that it is probably easier to figure out what kind of automorphisms there are, when you write the group in this somewhat canonical form.

Comment: thank you ,(I have learned if the whole  group is cyclic,we can use Euler function φ to compute its automorphism group order in my algebra class ,but I don't know how to compute the product groups' order after decomposing the 1155 into the cyclic groups product.   Are there exist lemmas to compute product group's automorphism which I have little knowledge about it?)@Jyrki Lahtonen♦

Comment: Jackunir, probably there are formulas. I just don't remember them, so my method was a bit ad hoc. IIRC Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I, chapter 3* has a formula, but I'm not sure whether it was for automorphisms or endomorphisms. Anyway, the idea to use invariant factors is described there. Probably in other texts on abstract algebra as well.

Comment: thank you，the book what i learnt conclude little about automorphisms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first rewrite the abelian group $G=\Bbb{Z}_{1155}^*$ in terms of its [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor). You already deduced that
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{1155}^*\simeq \Bbb{Z}_3^*\times\Bbb{Z}_5^*\times\Bbb{Z}_7^*\times\Bbb{Z}_{11}^*.
$$
We know that for a prime $p$, $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. Therefore
$$
G\simeq C_2\times C_4\times C_6\times C_{10}.
$$
Recall the rule that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $C_m\times C_n\simeq C_{mn}$. Here $C_6\simeq C_2\times C_3$ and $C_{10}\simeq C_2\times C_5$. Regrouping gives thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
G&\simeq C_2\times C_4\times(C_2\times C_3)\times(C_2\times C_5)\\
&\simeq (C_4\times C_3\times C_5)\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2\\
&\simeq C_{60}\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
IMHO it is easier to count the number of automorphisms of $G$ from this.
Let $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ be generators for the four factors, so $c_1$ is of order $60$ and $c_2,c_3,c_4$ are all of order two. We get all the elements of $G$ uniquely in the form $\prod_{i=1}^4 c_i^{a_i}$ with $0\le a_1<60$,
$a_2,a_3,a_4\in\{0,1\}$.

Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $G$. Then obviously $\sigma(c_1)$ is of order $60$. Therefore we must have $\sigma(c_1)=c_1^{a_1}c_2^{a_2}c_3^{a_3}c_4^{a_4}$ with
$\gcd(a_1,60)=1$ but no constraints on the other exponents. There are $\phi(60)=2\cdot(3-1)\cdot(5-1)=16$ choices for $a_1$, and two choices for the other exponents - a total of $16\cdot2^3=128$ choices for $\sigma(c_1)$ (we shall shortly see that all these choices lead to automorphisms of $\sigma$). Let us record the fact that because $a_1$ is necessarily odd we have $\phi(c_1^{30})=c_1^{30}$. Furthermore, this is the only element of order two in $\langle \sigma(c_1)\rangle$ (a cyclic group of an even order has a unique element of order two).

The elements of order two in $G$ are exactly the fifteen non-trivial elements of the elementary 2-abelian subgroup $H$ generated by $\{c_1^{30},c_2,c_3,c_4\}$. Of these $c_1^{30}=\sigma(c_1^{30})$ has already been used. This means that fourteen possible choices remain for $\sigma(c_2)$.

From this point the calculation proceeds very similarly to the calculation of  the number of invertible matrices modulo two. Namely, $\sigma(c_3)$ can be any element of $G$ that is of order two, but is not in the subgroup generated by $\sigma(c_1^{30})$ and $\sigma(c_2)$ (otherwise $\sigma$ won't be injective). The latter condition rules out $4$ of the $16$
elements of $H$, and, given $\sigma(c_1)$ and $\sigma(c_2)$, we have $12$ choices for $\sigma(c_3)$.

Repeating the above calculation/argument we see that we have $8$ choices for $\sigma(c_4)$, namely the elements of $H\setminus\langle \sigma(c_1^{30})=c_1^{30},\sigma(c_2),\sigma(c_3)\rangle$. We easily see that all these combinations of choices lead to an injective homomorphism from $G$ to itself, hence to an automorphism. So, finally:

> The number of automorphisms of the group $\Bbb{Z}_{1155}^*$ is $$|Aut(G)|=128\cdot14\cdot12\cdot8=2^{13}\cdot3\cdot7.$$

---

I won't give you the structure of $Aut(G)$ (I don't know how to do that concisely). I do want to point out that $Aut(G)$ obviously has a subgroup isomorphic to the simple group $GL_3(\Bbb{F}_2)$ of order $168$. In particular, $Aut(G)$ is not a solvable group.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm learning too little about how to solve these problem.would you like to teach me the idea about decomposing it and then recombine asC60×C2×C2×C2 .the aim to recombine C60 is it easy to compute?is there exist some common number that can be our first thinking ？@Jyrki Lahtonen♦(I am a freshman and learning undergraduate course just before this vocation )

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. We have $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361651/aut-mathbb-z-p-simeq-mathbb-z-p-1).
2. We know Aut $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb{Z}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350543/am-i-correct-regarding-autz-n), and [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316731/determine-the-isomorphism-classes-of-operatornameaut-mathbbz-2-times-math?rq=1).
3. You have obtained already, that $p=3,5,7,11$.
4. Jyrki's objection for the invariant factors, i.e., to write the direct product of these four cyclic groups in a canonical form.